# Unable to connect to Mac Server with Address='IP Address' and User='Username'. The build can't continue without a connection

Tags: macos, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a problem.
My Visual Studio 2019 (16.8.2)  is connected to my virtual Mac on VMware but getting build from the project gives the following error. I use the latest version of XCode, vs 2019 on PC , vs on Mac

Error message

> Unable to connect to Mac Server with Address='192.168.1.149' and User='{username}'. The build can't continue without a connection App2.iOS

Comment: You have to use bridge connection for your virtual machine to allow the Windows machine's connecting request.
Refer to this documentation https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/108509/how-to-connect-visualstudio-with-xamarin-to-virtual-macos for the details steps and information.

Comment: set connection to bridge connection . no fixed problem

Comment: You could post the issue to **Help->Send Feedback->report a problem**.